# Python argparse throws IndexError in Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm running Python 3.6.4 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit) on Win7. I pulled this example right out of https://pymotw.com/3/argparse/index.html#module-argparse and don't understand why `parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Short sample app')` throws this exception when instantiating the parser.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-a75bf8c17dc8> in <module>()
----> 1 parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Short sample app')
      2 
      3 parser.add_argument('-a', action="store_true", default=False)
      4 parser.add_argument('-b', action="store", dest="b")
      5 parser.add_argument('-c', action="store", dest="c", type=int)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\argparse.py in __init__(self, prog, usage, description, epilog, parents, formatter_class, prefix_chars, fromfile_prefix_chars, argument_default, conflict_handler, add_help, allow_abbrev)
   1620         # default setting for prog
   1621         if prog is None:
-> 1622             prog = _os.path.basename(_sys.argv[0])
   1623 
   1624         self.prog = prog

IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: To clarify, I know that I can add a prog='blah' to override this behavior. I'm just not clear why this is required.

Comment: Apparently, Anaconda isn't setting the value of `_sys.argv` correctly. Whether this is a bug in Anaconda (for not doing so), a bug in `argparse` (for assuming `_sys.argv[0]` will exist) or both isn't clear.

Comment: Although the fact that the error says the *string* index (and not *list* index) is puzzling.

Comment: What does `print(sys.argv)` show if you call that before you create the parser?

Comment: 'print(sys.argv)' shows 
  
  ['C:\\Users\\XXXXXXX\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\ipykernel_launcher.py', '-f', 'C:\\Users\\XXXXXXX\\AppData\\Roaming\\jupyter\\runtime\\kernel-b0ae8661-3f4e-40c4-8db5-fa20dfb6ccfd.json']

Comment: Deleted this comment - please ignore